# Changing color text using button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried changing text color of my html using javascript . After few tries I realised i cant change the color if i am changing it in css. So basically it means CSS is executed at the end?? and how can i change the color of the text after clicking the button if i am changing it in css as well? Sorry i am new

```
function changecol()
      { 
          var html=document.body;

          html.style.backgroundColor='black';
          html.style.color='white';

      }
```

Expected all the lines in my html to turn white but only those where i have not applied css became white

Comment: Where/when do you call `changecol`? By the way, spell out the name, like `changeColor`. `col` could mean column, or color, or... whatever.

Comment: I suspect the issue is that there are other elements in the document which have `color` and `backgroundColor` attributes set directly in your CSS - this takes precedence over the styles inherited from the `body`, even if the latter are inline styles. If you want to change the color scheme based on a button-click, the best way is to have it toggle a class on the `body` or `html` element, and use that in your CSS selectors to give effectively 2 different stylesheets.

Answer (score 0):

This is a jquery approach, that will change your color on button click:

```js
$("#butt").on("click",function(){
          $(".color").css("background-color","red");
          $(".color").css("color","white");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="color">HALLO</div>
<button id="butt">Change Color</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably dealing with an inheritance problem. In your case, you are putting a style on the body, and the only elements that inherit styles from the body are ones without their own style. To solve this, I recommend applying the style directly to each element.

Try this:

```
function changecol(){
  document.body.style.backgroundColor='black';
  document.body.style.color='white';

  // change background color of each element 
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('*');
  for(let i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
    elements[i].style.backgroundColor='black';
    elements[i].style.color='white';
  }
}
```